# Roblox Datastore has DNS errors for only one key?

Tags: lua, roblox

I have a datastore that holds player data. For some reason, when I try to :GetAsync the data for my user ID, it returns error 502 DnsResolve. When I try to :GetAsync the data for any other user ID, it works perfectly fine.

```
local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local PlayersDataStore = DataStoreService:GetDataStore("Players")
local Success, PlayerData = pcall(function()
    return PlayersDataStore:GetAsync(0) --Where I store my player data template
end)
print(Success, PlayerData)
--true table: 0x001b6d8bf2866b07

local Success, PlayerData = pcall(function()
    return PlayersDataStore:GetAsync(UserId) --Only my user ID fails??
end)
print(Success, PlayerData)
--true 502: API Services rejected request with error. HTTP unknown error (HttpError: DnsResolve)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seemed to have fixed the problem by doing:

```
PlayersDataStore:SetAsync(UserId, "Test")
```

Certainly something backend was erroneous.